# Can someone explain this table CSS issue I'm having?

Tags: html, css

Can someone explain why the widths of the contents of the table are all different. Also, is there a way to make is so all the widths are the same.

By contents I mean 'items', 'price', 'quantity', 'subtotal'

HTML

```
<div id="cart_items">
<table class="ty-cart-content ty-table">  
    <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="ty-cart-content__title ty-items">Item</th>
                <th class="ty-cart-content__title ty-left">Price</th>
                <th class="ty-cart-content__title quantity-cell">Quantity</th>
                <th class="ty-cart-content__title ty-price">Subtotal</th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

CSS

```
div {
    color: #333;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}

div#cart_items {
    border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.ty-table {
    width: 100%;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uwfosLgp/

Comment: Actually table-cell's `height` follows `horizontally` and `width` `vertically`, in your case, you haven't defined any width to the `<th>` so they consuming automatic assigned `width` for equal assignment you can go for `<th widht=25%">` or can write `CSS` for it. OR as @SergeS explained you can go for `table-layout: fixed` property viz quite useful in your case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make sure that all columns are same width (Without knowing their count) you can use `table-layout: fixed` . Then renderer will ignore size of contents, and will render all columns with same width (Or if you set width, it won't allow it to be changed by content)

Here is your updated example

https://jsfiddle.net/Lmdn8xp5/

EDIT: I don't see second result with adding widths there - so to have complete answers, second option is to add widths to all columns (To the header for example)